# Has anyone ever built BZR 2.7.0 for Windows?

Tags: bazaar

In the past we used BZR 2.6b1 on Windows for many of our professional projects. 
This turned out to not be a good choice, and some of our projects suffered when we encountered some bugs in BZR 2.6, which might have been specific to the Windows version, or might not. Years passed, the bugs never got fixed, and so we began to migrating to git.

However, some of our older projects are still in Bazaar, and having returned to the Bazaar website for the first time in 2.5 years, I can see there is now a 2.7.0 release, but no Windows version of it.

I can see [this message on the Ubuntu mailing-list](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/bazaar/2016q1/076089.html), in which somebody has mentioned their intention to build 2.7.0 for Windows, but the mailing-list thread ends without a conclusion.

So the question is, short of compiling it myself, has anyone ever created a Windows version of 2.7.0, as an installer or archive of compiled binaries, and is it still available?

Answer (score 2):

There are no Windows installers for Bazaar 2.7 as far as I know. We're likely to build installers for [Breezy](https://launchpad.net/brz) (a friendly fork of Bazaar that is active) on Windows once it is ready for release, but that may take a couple of months.